# Appending dictionary with new keys and values in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I'm currently trying to loop through a dataframe for linear regression. After each iteration, I want to save the current column name and the resulting Adj. R squared value in a dictionary:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

for columns in [x for x in var_sel.columns if x != 'price']:
    
    fit_d = {}
    
    Y = var_sel['price']

    X = var_sel[columns]

    X = sm.add_constant(X)

    model = sm.OLS(Y,X, missing = 'drop').fit()
    
    fit_d[columns] = model.rsquared
```

But when I print the dictionary it only outputs `{'room_type_Shared room': 0.0003039648861731248}` which is the last column of the dataframe. How do I append the dictionary with each iteration result?

Comment: declare a dictionary outside and append the value as the iteration progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare the dictionary outside the for loop. in your above code, you are redeclaring the dictionary everytime when the loop runs.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

fit_d = {}

for columns in [x for x in var_sel.columns if x != 'price']:
    
    Y = var_sel['price']

    X = var_sel[columns]

    X = sm.add_constant(X)

    model = sm.OLS(Y,X, missing = 'drop').fit()
    
    fit_d[columns] = model.rsquared
```